# Add class to specific line in results.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to dynamically add a class to a column of cells in a table, depending on the current time. As you can see below, the class I want to dynamically add is called "cell-timenow":

```
                < tbody >
                {
                    results.map(result =>
                        <tr key={result.title} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <td>{result.t00}</td>
                            <td>{result.t01}</td>
                            <td>{result.t02}</td>
                            <td>{result.t03}</td>
                            <td>{result.t04}</td>
                            <td>{result.t05}</td>
                            <td className="cell-timenow">{result.t06}</td>
                            <td>{result.t07}</td>
                            <td>{result.t08}</td>
                            <td>{result.t09}</td>
                            <td>{result.t10}</td>
                            <td>{result.t11}</td>
                            <td>{result.t12}</td>
                            <td>{result.t13}</td>
                            <td>{result.t14}</td>
                            <td>{result.t15}</td>
                            <td>{result.t16}</td>
                            <td>{result.t17}</td>
                            <td>{result.t18}</td>
                            <td>{result.t19}</td>
                            <td>{result.t20}</td>
                            <td>{result.t21}</td>
                            <td>{result.t22}</td>
                            <td>{result.t23}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                }
            </tbody>
```

The cell it is added to changes based on the current time. I know how to add the class using "classList.add('cell-timenow')", but is there an efficient method of adding the class using the results.map function?

EDIT: T00 corresponds to hour 0, and T01 corresponds to hour 1, and so on.
EDIT2: Fixed error in class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `results` array looks something like this :

```
const results = [
  { t00: '00:00', t01: '01:00' /* ... */ },
  { t00: '00:00', t01: '01:00' /* ... */ },
  { t00: '00:00', t01: '01:00' /* ... */ },
  // ...
]
```

in the `render` function, you could prepare the table rows like this:

```
render () {
  const currentTime = '02:00' // For example

  results = results.map(result => {
    let rowNodes = []
    for (const hour in result) {
      rowNodes.push(
        <td
          key={hour}
          className={result[hour] === currentTime ? 'cell-timenow' : ''}
        >result[hour]</td>
      )
    }

    return (
      <tr
        key={result.title}
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
      >rowNodes</tr>
    )

  })

  return (<table>{results}</table>)

}
```